# What is the correct way to download code from another module of the multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module

What is the correct way to download code of another module of the multi-module maven project?

I have the multi-module maven project that consists of 2 modules. I have implemented first module and now I need some classes from my first module in the second module. How the corect way to perform it?

Comment: add a dependency to tmodule one in the second module I'd say. Note, you're not allowed to have cyclic dependencies

Comment: Yes as AKSW said adding dependency would work. If you work on Intellij Idea, it will suggest you to add dependency when you try to import the class.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the first module as a dependency of the second as you would normally.

Comment: should be the other way around, or not? He needs classes from module 1, thus, he needs a dependency to module 1 in module 2

Comment: Sorry, you're right - I misread the question. I'll fix my post.

Comment: @YarikSoltys you might consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.